# How to show partially evaluated method source in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, logging

Bear with me, this is an off-beat questions.

What I want to achieve is being able to log how a calculation was performed in a method.

Lets say we have this simple method inside a model. It performs a calculation and returns a result. Awesome.

```
def calc_reduction_factor
  (numerator + 3) / denominator 
end
```

The issue I am having is that the auditing requires all the calculations to be logged (when report is produced, not when function is run). So for this example with numbers:

```
puts "(#{model.numenator} + 3) / #{model.denominator} = #{model.calc_reduction_factor}"
>> (5 + 3) / 2 = 4
```

I am lazy and sometimes forgetful. If the function requires a change the logging would have to be changed too. This is a small example but in the future there might be hundreds different calc methods.

I am looking for a solution that will be able to print out the source of the function and also do the math. Closest I found was [dentaku](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku) library. Could store string in a repo and then print them for loggin or evaluate for calc purposes. But it looks like it haven't been updated in a while and is a little slow.

Comment: You could look at a tool like [`ruby2ruby`](http://docs.seattlerb.org/ruby2ruby/) which helps give you a parse tree, something you can navigate and potentially evaluate bit by bit.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps [the `method_source`](https://github.com/banister/method_source#example-display-method-source) gem solves your issue? This is, incidentally, what `pry` uses under the hood to display the source code of methods.

Comment: you could make the function return `"(#{numerator} + 3) / #{denominator}"` and then pass that string to `eval`.

Comment: @maxpleaner That actually works really well! Thank you. Creative solution